# Combining study in AI with other Computer Science fields

Tags: career

I am studying for an MSc in AI and I am currently thinking about attending a bootcamp on a computer science subject.

The motive is that I want to gain hands on experince on practical applications and the MSc course may be a bit too "academic".

The question is: which subjects combine well with an MSc in AI. For example a bootcamp in Machine Learning will have a huge overlap which means waste of time, while a bootcamp on web developemnt will be very different, so much so, that I am afraid the MSc in AI might seem irrelevant to an employer who needs a web developer.

Is data engineering e.g. a good middle ground? What about software engineering?

Comment: We don't know what is your dream profession, let alone your tastes, so we can't answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust lets leave personal dreams and tasts aside for a moment. My question is whether it makes sense to study software engineering along with AI when ones goal is to get employed.

Comment: Why would it not ?